# Code to move from one table to other upon deletion, does it works

Tags: plsql, triggers

Code to move from one table to other upon deletion, is this correct?

```
 create or replace TRIGGER Trans_history_s
    AFTER DELETE
        ON trans_s
        REFERENCING NEW AS trans_s
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO trans_history_s values (:old.book_no,:old.mem_no,sysdate,sysdate,sysdate);
    END;
```

Comment: It looks like it might work.  You should list the column names in the insert statement (`INSERT INTO trans_history_s (col1, col2, ...)...`) and the `referencing` line does nothing useful and can be removed,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct and as @TonyAndrews has already stated, you should always explicitly define the columns you are referring to, to avoid relying on the column order.

Keep in mind that - [though possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939735/re-order-columns-of-table-in-oracle) - you should never rely on the order of columns in a table. When adding columns, Oracle will always put these at the end.